# Firestore Security Rules: If timestamp (FieldValue.serverTimestamp) equals now

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

How do I check if user on client sided created document with only `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`?

I have following:

```
allow create: if request.resource.data.timestamp == ??
```

What should I have instead of `??`. I have tried `serverTimestamp()` `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`, `now` or `now()` but it doesn't work.

It is possible to do it in Firebase like this:

```
".validate": "newData.child('timestamp').val() === now"
```

I am looking for the same solution. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can access the current request timestamp in Security Rules using the `request.time` attribute ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#properties)), which is the Firestore equivalent to the Realtime Databases's `now`. You'll therefore want something like:

```
allow create: if request.resource.data.timestamp == request.time;
```

For `serverTimestamp()` this should evaluate to true.

You **should always** validate client input in Security Rules, even if you're using `serverTimestamp()`. Security Rules doesn't automatically know the server input the value instead of the client, so without this check, a malicious client could create a different created at time.